# Закрыть доступ к страницам меню в WP

Tags: wordpress

На сайте есть два меню.
Как запретить переход по страницам одного из меню, если пользователь не авторизован ( вывести ему сообщение об авторизации )

Comment: "сообщение о НЕОБХОДИМОСТИ авторизации" нужно выводить при ПОПАДАНИИ на такие страницы  не авторизованных пользователей. Независимо от того, как на них попадают. А меню можно СКРЫТЬ от не авторизованных.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) для определения, залогинен ли пользователь, и в зависимости от возвращаемого результата выводить меню со ссылками на страницы или меню со списком страниц без ссылок, но с выводом модального окна авторизации по клику